# Running Chrome on an AWS micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vnc, google-chrome

Let me start by saying my server administration experience is limited, so please forgive me if I'm making assumptions that might seem odd.

I've written an extension for Google Chrome and I'd like to test its stability when left running continuously for days, but unfortunately I have no access to a pc or laptop that I can leave on 24/7. So my idea is to set up a EC2 micro instance with ubuntu, then install ubuntu-desktop and a vnc server, and finally connect via vnc to the instance, access to the graphical desktop interface, install Google Chrome, add my extension and let it run there.

Does this sound feasible, or is it a silly idea? What are the potential limitations I could run into?

Comment: You don't know anyone in the entire world who could beta test for you?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'd rather be in control of the testing first if the cost/effort in doing so is not ridiculously high, and I figured having a micro instance running wouldn't in theory be a big deal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS gives you complete control of the OS so what you're suggesting makes sense.

The main disadvantages of running a GUI over the network come down to bandwidth and latency issues, so you might want to consider getting an EC2 instance as close to your region as possible.

Keep in mind AWS Security groups, which will need to be configured to allow your VNC connection.

Micro Instances aren't really made for production use, so you may find it's not really a true test of a typical system. You should factor this into your test as it may be more appropriate to use a small instance type.

Other than that, sounds like a reasonable solution.

Comment: That's what I thought aswell, but I wanted to be sure since it isn't very common for devs to do this. Thanks for your input!