# How to install chrome inside AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

How do I install Chrome in AWS Lambda? I know I might need a specific file from an EC2 instance but I can't figure out how to retrieve it.

not duplicate as as a micro instance ec2 won't be the same enviroment as a lambda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Chrome on an AWS micro instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468855/running-chrome-on-an-aws-micro-instance)

Comment: @animusmind not duplicate as as a micro instance ec2 won't be the same enviroment as a lambda

Comment: Chrome typically means "Google Chrome", the cross-platform browser. It doesn't make sense to install a browser in an environment like AWS Lambda. Do you mean something else, like headless Chrome? Also, you've tagged this question with 'java'. How does java relate to your question?

Comment: @jarmod People have done it for scimmers. To use headless chrome you would need to install it (or at least that what a couple of sources say). I tagged it with Java because that the language I used to write the lambda function in

Comment: So, what is it that you want to do exactly? I still don't understand.

Comment: @jarmod I need to be able to install google chrome into a lambda's environment so I can run headless chrome correctly

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to do this on a Lambda via a ECR Image and it took me several days (including checking in this thread) to come to an easy answer. The  Dockerimage on this repo https://github.com/umihico/docker-selenium-lambda/ was pretty close to perfect for me. Its for python, but it will install the necessary libraries if you want to use java. I tried posting as an answer given it took me 5 days and a lot of wasted time scrolling around stackoverflow, but moderation does not allow links to similar answers. I genuinely hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Lambda Layer with a compiled Google Chrome. There are docker containers emulating Lambda execution environment, e.g. "lambci/lambda:java8". Could be tricky, since you need to build the browser from source code yourself, while there may be many dependencies missing.

Have you tried looking at other people's solutions? For example, this repo seems to have an already compiled Lambda Layer with Google Chrome [Google Chrome for AWS Lambda as a layer](https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer)

Comment: Lambda layer is Javascript based, I need a java based solution if possible otherwise I would have to rework huge portions of it.

Comment: Absolutely not true. A Lambda Layer is an archive that is extracted into "/opt". Please have a look here: [Including Library Dependencies in a Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path). My idea was to compile it as a binary and call through ProcessBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the requirement for Java in this case. It's not your friend.

Switch to Node.js, if only for this Lambda, and use [alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) and [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Comment: I'm seriously considering this however the entire project is based on Java and could result in rewriting huge portions of the code to fix it. I need a Java based solution

Comment: Maybe find a way to use both. Not sure what your workflow is but if it's scrape then process the results, may do the scraping and web page manipulation in Node.js, deliver the results to S3, and trigger your subsequent Java Lambda to process it. If the workflow is driven by your Java code (rather than post-scraping) then build a Node.js scraper that you can send API commands to via API Gateway, and control it from your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

As AWS Lambda recently announced (2020) the Container Image Support, you can *bring your own runtime* for your Java code.

A sample Docker Image might look like the following:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:11

RUN yum install -y wget unzip libX11

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm && \
    yum install -y google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

COPY target/dependency ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/
COPY target/classes ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD ["de.rieckpil.test.InvokeWebDriver::handleRequest"]
```

Once you push this Docker Image to your ECR, you can create a Lambda function that uses your image.

However, I'm still unable to launch Chrome 89 (already tried a gazillion of `ChromeOptions` arguments combinations) ...

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 46: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
```

Maybe someone in the future has more success with this and can use this as a template :D

Comment: Did you find a fix? I'm facing the same issue 'touch: cannot touch '/home/sbx_user1051/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list': No such file or directory'. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76998462/google-chrome-tries-to-create-mimeapps-list-on-ubuntu-docker-image-hosted-on-aws