# Can' Hosting a Web Scraper Because of Chrome Installation

Tags: web-scraping, nestjs, puppeteer

I want to create a web scraper using nestjs and host it on https://app.cyclic.sh/. The problem is after i deployed the website, the web scraper doesn't work anymore because of this:

Could not find Chrome (ver. 119.0.6045.105). This can occur if either

1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/puppeteer)

I put the installation script in package.json, but it keeps giving me the error. Here is my package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npx puppeteer browsers install chrome && nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "node dist/main",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's the deal, when you run these commands to install the browser it won't work because it won't install it globally on the instance of your server, it's probably doing it in a different directory or probably inside your application entry point.

What you should do is run the installation outside of your package.json scripts. In your local machine it probably works because you already have it by default.

Since you are using Ciclyc which deploys your application on AWS Lambda it's going to be nearly impossible to achieve this because you don't manage the creation of this instance unless you do some dark magic, but if you want to give it a try here's a question that might help you out:

[How to install chrome inside AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876521/how-to-install-chrome-inside-aws-lambda)

Since I know you probably aren't using Docker I think the easiest way to do it would be changing your implementation of puppeteer and the chrome dependency and start using chrome-aws-lambda package. Add it to your package.json file and do something similar to what's explained on this post:

https://dev.to/qaproengineer/how-to-deploy-puppeteer-with-aws-lambda-2goe

My own advice would be to manage the deploy yourself using your own instance in AWS and deploy using a Docker container, that will allow you to play around with the actual instance and install the dependencies you need. Here's an example of how a Dockerfile with chromium installation would work (I used chromium, but it should work similarly to your use case):

```
FROM node:17-alpine
ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser" \
  PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
RUN set -x \
  && apk update \
  && apk upgrade \
  && apk add --no-cache \
  udev \
  ttf-freefont \
  chromium 

WORKDIR /tmp

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Replace for correct PORT
EXPOSE 3000

# Run it
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/tmp/dist/main"]
```